# Removing nodes from XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This removes all elements from the document:

```
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(inputFile);
        foreach (XElement element in document.Elements())
        {
            element.Remove();
        }
        document.Save(outputFile);
```

This doesn't have any effect:

```
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(inputFile);
        foreach (XElement element in document.Elements())
        {
            //element.Remove();
            foreach (XElement child in element.Elements())
                child.Remove();
        }
        document.Save(outputFile);
```

Am I missing something here? Since these are all references to elements within the XDocument, shouldn't the changes take effect? Is there some other way I should be removing nested children from an XDocument?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Are you sure that element.Elements() is returning child elements? Just looking for a bit more information about exactly what you are seeing happen.

Comment: @jrista It is returning child elements, but the problem seems to be with the enumerator behaving differently after a `.Remove()`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect. Enumerators generally throw exceptions when you modify the collection, as they are very dependent upon the stability of the underlying collection to function properly. I am actually surprised you can continue after removing a node while using a foreach/enumerator. I would generally recommend using a while loop (or possibly for...but thats more complicated), rather than a foreach.

Comment: @jrista When you put it that way it makes a lot more sense. Silent failure always gives me a headache :/

Comment: Yeah, I hate silent failures. I'm really surprised thats happening here, as usually, iteration + collection modification in .NET means an exception is thrown. I dug through the XDocument code in reflector, and the way .Remove() works is really round-about, and involves the creation of an internal list at one point. I'm guessing thats why the remove is succeeding and not throwing...but it will definitely mess up enumeration since the collection's state changes, and the enumerator does not know that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently when you iterate over `element.Elements()`, calling a `Remove()` on one of the children causes the enumerator to `yield break`. Iterating over `element.Elements().ToList()` fixed the problem.

Comment: Is this specific to XPath then?

Comment: @Neo In what way? As [jirsta](http://stackoverflow.com/users/111554/jrista) pointed out above, most enumerators will break when the underlying collection changes.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that an InvalidOperationException occurs normally. My question is about `yield break`. Is this specific to XPath vis-à-vis @jrista's comment re silent failing?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of another way using System.Xml.XPath (change the xpath query to suit your needs):

```
const string xml = 
    @"<xml>
        <country>
            <states>
                <state>arkansas</state>
                <state>california</state>
                <state>virginia</state>
            </states>
        </country>
    </xml>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
doc.XPathSelectElements("//xml/country/states/state[.='arkansas']").ToList()
   .ForEach(el => el.Remove());;
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `XDocument` try this instead:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(inputFile);
foreach (XElement element in document.Elements())
{
     document.Element("Root").SetElementValue(element , null);
}
document.Save(outputFile)
```

Regards,
Todd