# How do delete data using XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Suppose I have an xml file as under

```
<DataBaseServers>
  <DataBaseServer id="1" title="IISDevdb1" address="Address1">
    <DataBases>      
      <database id="1" name="db1" userID="u1" password="p1" />
      <database id="3" name="db3" userID="u3" password="p3" />
    </DataBases>
  </DataBaseServer>
  <DataBaseServer id="2" title="iis2" address="Address2">
  <DataBases>      
      <database id="2" name="db2" userID="u2" password="p2" />    
    </DataBases>
  </DataBaseServer>
</DataBaseServers>
```

I want to delete database id="3".

The resulting xml will be

```
<DataBaseServers>
  <DataBaseServer id="1" title="IISDevdb1" address="Address1">
    <DataBases>      
      <database id="1" name="db1" userID="u1" password="p1" />     
    </DataBases>
  </DataBaseServer>
  <DataBaseServer id="2" title="iis2" address="Address2">
  <DataBases>      
      <database id="2" name="db2" userID="u2" password="p2" />    
    </DataBases>
 </DataBaseServer>
</DataBaseServers>
```

If I delete database id="2", the xml will look as

```
<DataBaseServers>
  <DataBaseServer id="1" title="IISDevdb1" address="Address1">
    <DataBases>      
      <database id="1" name="db1" userID="u1" password="p1" />
      <database id="3" name="db3" userID="u3" password="p3" />
    </DataBases>
  </DataBaseServer>
  <DataBaseServer id="2" title="iis2" address="Address2"/>
 </DataBaseServers>
```

How can I do it using XDocument?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the list of elements of XDocument and use `element.Remove();` method.as:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(@"Doc\abc.xml")); ;
        foreach (XElement element in document.Document.Descendants("database").ToList())
        {
            if(element.Attribute("id").Value == Convert.ToString(3))
            element.Remove();
        }
        document.Save(Server.MapPath(@"Doc\abc1.xml"));
```

See [Removing nodes from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215470/removing-nodes-from-xdocument)

Comment: I want to delete database id="3".Then how can i do so?

Comment: actually it was for demo only, Now I have updated the code, check it

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it

```
xdoc.Descendants("database")
.Where(xa => xa.Attribute("id").Value == Convert.ToString(3))
.Remove();
```

Comment: There's no need to call `Convert.ToString(3)`.  `(xa => xa.Attribute("id").Value == "3")` will work just fine.

Comment: Note however that if you have more than one "database" element that has an id of "3", it will delete all of them.